difference between negative and positive numbers font
enter image description hereI have a user form and list box on it .the font of list box set to persian font ( b nazanin).while negative numbers is Farsi(b nazanin font) and the font of positive numbers and zero  is English. I want all font to be Farsi.
what can i do for this ?
